# Why use "getObject" method when writing a Factory class?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

Typically a `Factory` class contains a method like `getObject`.

Thereby

```
class Factory
{
    private $type;

    function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    function getObject()
    {
        //example for brevity only to show use of $type variable
        if ($this->type) $object = new $type();
        return $object;
    }
}
```

**Question:**  Why not return object straight via constructor?

```
class Factory
{
    function __construct($type)
    {
        if ($type) $object = new $type();
        return $object;
    }

}
```

Comment: note that there are two factory patterns, [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [factory-method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (with some slight difefrences)

Comment: @Dennis Can I somehow improve my answer for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can not return anything except your own instance from the constructor. The whole point of an constructor is to set up an instance. The whole point of a factory is to abstract some complex construction / setup logic from the user.

A factory class has usually a static method like:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct($x, $y) {
        // do something
    }

    // this is a factory method
    public static function createFromPoint(Point $point) {
        return new self($point->x, $point->y);
    }
}

$foo = Foo::createFromPoint(new Point(1, 1)); // makes no sense but shows the concept
```

Comment: good point!  Thanks.  And the example ... .. does make no sense!  You can pretty much call the class with `$x` and `$y`, but here you can do it using "a factory way"

Comment: It is just to show what the factory is for. Imagine a complex constructor with many dependencies and additional configuration routine (like calling methods, and maybe register the created instance in the garbage collector or whatever). It enables you to reuse a lot of this logic.

Comment: note that there are two factory patterns, [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [factory-method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (with some slight difefrences) (reference  Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software, aka GoF book)

Comment: @NikosM. Sure, you're right, but I think he is looking for the first one.